# Odd, Even, Zero Counter

Tags: c++

I have to write a code that counts the number of odd numbers, even numbers, and zeros in a multi-digit long variable, here is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int lab14(long num, int &even, int &odd, int &zero){

    while (num > 0){

        long w = num;
        w = num%10;

        if (w % 2 == 1){
            odd++;
        }

        else if (w % 2 == 0 && w != 0){
            even++;
        }

        else if (w == 0 ){
            zero++;
        }

        num = num/10;

    }
    return odd;
    return even;
    return zero;
}

int main() {

    int even = 0, odd = 0, zero = 0;
    int num;

    cout << "#############################" << endl;

    cout << "## Even, odd, zero counter " << endl;

    bool flag = true;

    while (flag){

    cout << "## Please enter a #: "; cin >>num;


    lab14(num, even, odd, zero);

    cout << "## Even numbers: "<<  even << endl
         << "## Odd Numbers: " << odd << endl
         << "## Zeros: " << zero << endl;

    cout << "## Enter 1 to go again, 0 to exit: "; cin >> flag ; cout << endl;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

For some reason, I'm getting really weird outputs. Can anyone help me out, for example:

```
## Please enter a #: 245
## Even numbers: 3
## Odd Numbers: 13
## Zeros: 0
## Enter 1 to go again, 0 to exit: 1

## Please enter a #: 342
## Even numbers: 5
## Odd Numbers: 14
## Zeros: 0
## Enter 1 to go again, 0 to exit:
```

Comment: 3 returns in one function ? And your compiler doesn't complain?

Comment: Is the output you are posting the full output? You should reset odd and even before calling lab14(). It might return the right result the first time you run it, does it? (apart from the three returns that do not make much sense. However, they should compile completely fine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are.

```
#include <iostream>

void lab14( unsigned long long int num, unsigned int &even, unsigned int &odd, unsigned int &zero )
{
    const unsigned long long Base = 10;

    even = odd = zero = 0;

    do
    {
        long long int digit = num % Base;

        if ( digit % 2 != 0 ) ++odd;
        else digit == 0 ? ++zero : ++even;
    } while ( num /= Base );        
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "#############################" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "## Even, odd, zero counter " << std::endl << std::endl;;


    while ( true )
    {
        std::cout << "## Please enter a # (0-exit): "; 

        unsigned long long int num = 0;
        std::cin >>num;

        if ( !num ) break;

        unsigned int even, odd, zero;

        lab14( num, even, odd, zero );

        std::cout << "## Even numbers: "<<  even << std::endl
                  << "## Odd Numbers: " << odd << std::endl
                  << "## Zeros: " << zero << std::endl;

        std::cout << std::endl;            
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If to enter

```
123456789012345678
```

and then

```
0
```

then the output will be

```
#############################
## Even, odd, zero counter 

## Please enter a # (0-exit): 123456789012345678
## Even numbers: 8
## Odd Numbers: 9
## Zeros: 1

## Please enter a # (0-exit): 0
```

As for your function then I think that it is too complicated with the three return statements:)

```
return odd;
return even;
return zero;
```

They would be enough for three separate functions.

As for me then I decided that the function does not require a return statement.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the same counter variables **by reference** to your function `lab14` without resetting them to zero between subsequent calls. This means that the counts are never reset the next time you call that function and so the totals keep on building giving you incorrect values on all but the first function call.

Add

```
even = 0;
odd = 0; 
zero = 0;
```

at the end of your loop after your `cout` calls to reset the variables. Alternatively zero them inside your `lab14` function before the `while` loop.

Incidentally, you have 3 return statments in that function - 2 of which are never reached.